# Eclipse Kepler error when initializing server

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-kepler, sap-business-technology-platform

When I try to run my Lean Java Server on eclipse I keep getting the error:

An internal error occurred during: "Starting LJS On-Premise Server" java.lang.nullPointerException.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sap.core.tools.eclipse.server.common.server.control.GenericSapServerBehavior.modifyDebugJvmParams(GenericSapServerBehavior.java:529)
at com.sap.core.tools.eclipse.server.common.server.control.GenericSapServerBehavior.rewriteLaunchFile(GenericSapServerBehavior.java:499)
at com.sap.core.tools.eclipse.server.common.server.control.GenericSapServerBehavior.removeDebugOptionsFromTheLaunchFile(GenericSapServerBehavior.java:481)
at com.sap.core.tools.eclipse.server.common.server.control.GenericSapServerBehavior.setupLaunch(GenericSapServerBehavior.java:462)
at org.eclipse.jst.server.generic.core.internal.ExternalLaunchConfigurationDelegate.launch(ExternalLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:102)
at com.sap.core.tools.eclipse.server.common.launch.SapExternalLaunchConfigurationDelegate.launch(SapExternalLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:87)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:858)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:707)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:700)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.startImpl2(Server.java:3538)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.startImpl(Server.java:3474)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server$StartJob.run(Server.java:367)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

I've tried:

- deleting the .metadata folder
- deleting the .settings folder
- restarting computer
- updating java
- deleting and reimporting the project
- redownloading eclipse, reconfiguring, reimporting the project

EDIT: My LJS was working previously. Suddenly it just stopped working and displayed the error.

Comment: Are you able to start tomcat server form command prompt?

Comment: No I cannot start the server at all.